# Kohana validation: своя функция проверки

Tags: валидация, kohana, php

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите пожалуйста как передать 2 параметра своей функции при валидации?
например в модели `Model_Categorys`

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
                'url' => array(
                    array('not_empty'),
                    array('max_length', array(':value', 255)),
                    array(array($this, 'check_url')),
                ),
                'parent_id' => array(
                    array('not_empty'),
                    array('numeric'),
                ),
        );    
    }
public function check_url($url)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

В этом варианте мы передаем функции 1 параметр, мне нужно что бы можно было так же передать значение поля `parent_id`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем понимаю что именно вы пытаетесь сделать, но полагаю, что "смотреть" нужно в сторону extra validation.

Comment: Я пытаюсь проверить существует ли введенная ссылка, но что бы проверка была правильной мне нужно получить не только значение поля url но и parent_id, сам способ проверки у меня есть, но требуется что бы так же передавалась значение parent_id а как это сделать я незнаю

Comment: а что у вас в parent_id?

Comment: в parent_id содержится id подкатегории в которую мы будем добавлять созданную категорию. Вся суть в том что бы проверить существует ли в этой подкатегории другие категории с url который указан в новой категории которую мы хотим создать, если нет то добавляем.

Comment: Почти совершенно случайно нашел ответ :)

                'url' => array(
                    array('not_empty'),
                    array('max_length', array(':value', 255)),
                    array(array($this, 'check_url'), array(':validation')),
                ),
                'parent_id' => array(
                    array('not_empty'),
                    array('numeric'),
                ),

    public function check_url($validation)
    {
        $parent_id = $validation['parent_id'];
        $url = $validation['url'];
        .......
    }

Comment: Только лучше использовать Arr::get($array, 'index') чтобы получать переменные из массивов